# Validation using ModelState MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

I am new to MVC so please help me with a simple problem i am facing. i have a class as follows

```
public class FeedbackViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Please enter feedback summary")]
    public string strSummary { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter feedback details")]
    public string strDetail { get; set; }
}
```

then this `FeedbackViewModel` is used in other viewmodel as

```
public class HomeIndexViewModel
{
    public SearchViewModel SearchViewModels { get; set; }
    public FeedbackViewModel FeedBackModel { get; set; }
}
```

my problem is in controller when I do `ModelState.IsValid` (model passed to action in controller is HomeIndexViewModel) is always true irrespective of whether I have entered any value in fields of `FeedbackViewModel` model. I need to validate `FeedbackViewModel` model in this action.

First is it possible then how. or if not possible then any work around is there. Please help I am stuck, I hope my question is clear

Comment: Don't use a viewModel in a viewModel.  Use a separate model for each view.  (Or share a single model with multiple views if it makes sense for your app).  And its typically better to keep complex objects out of view models when possible for the purposes of validating input.  Data annotations will not dig into complex properties.

Comment: Can you show the code for the controller action?

Comment: thanks for the reply. i think i will just seperate out the views as forty two said and keep things simple.

Answer (score 0):

As forty-two said in a comment above don't keep complex objects in a model its not worth the trouble. When I started working in MVC i had similiar issues which were solved by flattening the model.

For your current problem you could use

```
public class HomeIndexViewModel
{
    public SearchViewModel SearchViewModels { get; set; } // same thing as below.

    [Required(ErrorMessage="Please enter feedback summary")]
    public string FeedBackModelstrSummary  { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter feedback details")]
    public string FeedBackModelstrDetail  { get; set; }
}
```

Having it like that you can help yourself with a mapper library to unflatt and flat (ValueInjecter or AutoMapper I use both) from objects in your domain. Its better that way :).